# Handling Additional field for JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, struts2

I'm using JPA 1, Struts2 and AppEngine datastore.

I already have persisted objects in my web application. I want to add Boolean property to my existing entity. Because of this, the old objects already saved will have `null` value for this `Boolean` property.

This is my new property

```
private Boolean display = false;

public Boolean getDisplay() {
    return display;
}
public void setDisplay(Boolean display) {
    this.display = display;
}
```

How I am going to prevent `java.lang.NullPointerException` for `display` property?

Comment: If you want three options, you could change to an integer type or string type with three values, both of those I think can be mapped onto an enum. Then you can use the three values consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Below works:

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getDisplay())){

}
```

Condition below will throw NPE:

```
if (item.getDisplay()){
```

}

Comment: or populate all other records with that property so you can then query on it too (if that's a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to modify the existing data to be consistent with your "code".

There is discussion possible of course.

- Some will say: always check on null, program robust.
- Others will say: clean code, null is never possible in that case, so don't check on that.